# O que existe de errado nessa linha de print = ('Hello,' + full_name.title() + '!')?

Tags: python, python-2.7

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou novato em programação e estou seguindo os exercícios do livro do Eric Matthes. No editor de texto, digitei `print = ('Hello,' + full_name.title() + '!')` e apareceu uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: E qual foi a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Esta aqui:     
print = 'Hello,' + full_name.title() + '!'
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: É python3 mesmo? Ou é Python 2?

Comment: Parece-me que está rodando no Python 2, não no 3, então, de fato, tem erro. O problema é no `=` após o `print`. No Python 2, o `print` é uma declaração da linguagem e não permite atribuição. O correto é `print 'Hello'`, não `print = 'Hello'`.

Comment: é o Python 2.7.15. Será que é isso?

Comment: Bom, neste caso vou pesquisar como faço o update do python e tentarei rodar o programa novamente. Aviso-os o que tiver acontecido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No python 2 `print` é uma declaração de linguagem, não um objeto, ou seja usar o operador de igual `=` fazendo com print como se ele fosse uma variavel vai causar erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 14
    print = 'Hello,' + full_name.title() + '!'
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Veja que o `^` aponta o sinal de igual como sendo o erro da sintaxe, ou seja se pretende usar isto como variavel então use um nome que não seja de uma "função" ou palavra reservada, crie uma var intuitiva, por exemplo:

```
msg = 'Hello,' + full_name.title() + '!'
```

Agora se a intenção **é exibir**, basta remover o sinal de `=` e usar como usou na outra linha:

```
print full_name

print 'Hello,' + full_name.title() + '!'
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` se trata de uma declaração de linguagem, o erro está acontecendo pois quando você usa o operador de atribuição (`=`) tentando atribuir algo a `print`, o interpretador entende que isso se trata de um erro de sintaxe (`SyntaxError`).

Talvez você queira algo como:

```
name = "ada lovelace"

print( name.title() )
print( name.upper() )
print( name.lower() )

first_name = "ada"
last_name = "lovelace"
full_name = first_name + " " + last_name

print( full_name )

print( "Hello, " + full_name.title() + "!" )
```

Saída:

```
Ada Lovelace
ADA LOVELACE
ada lovelace
ada lovelace
Hello, Ada Lovelace!
```